# How to work with XML/XPath with asp-classic and parse String to xml Document

Tags: xpath, asp-classic, xml-parsing

What is the best way to read XML Xpath with asp-classic from String Request Param.

```
  <%    function FReadXml(pStringXml) 
  {
      var xDom = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument");
      var a = xDom.LoadXML(pStringXml)
      return a;
   }
var xml = Request.QueryString("xml").item;
try{
  var dom = FReadXml(xml);
  //work with xpath
 }catch(ex0){
  Response.Write("problems when read a xml: " + ex0.message);
 }
```

%>

Thanks, a lot.

Comment: The question is a little too general.  Provide a short example of the XML you need "parse" and indicate what data you would like to extract from it.

Comment: My question are, how to load document from string parameter, not from file name parameter! thanks.

Comment: You appear to be doing that already `LoadXML` is the method to use load a string containing XML into the dom.

Comment: yes, LoadXML is the method to load from string, no "load" thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't know what do you want to say with *parse String to xml Document* but i can help you with the part of using Xpath

you can load a single node using XPath with [SelectSingleNode({XPath Expression})](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms757846%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

```
var xmlDoc = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0");
var currNode;
xmlDoc.async = false;
xmlDoc.load("books.xml");
if (xmlDoc.parseError.errorCode != 0) {
   var myErr = xmlDoc.parseError;
   Response.write("You have error " + myErr.reason);
} else {
   xmlDoc.setProperty("SelectionLanguage", "XPath");
   currNode = xmlDoc.selectSingleNode("//book/author");
   Response.write(currNode.text);
}
```

or using [SelectNodes({XPath Expression})](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms754523%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
var xmlDoc = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0");
var objNodeList;
xmlDoc.async = false;
xmlDoc.load("hello.xsl");
if (xmlDoc.parseError.errorCode != 0) {
   var myErr = xmlDoc.parseError;
   Response.write("You have error " + myErr.reason);
} else {
   xmlDoc.setProperty("SelectionNamespaces",    "xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'");
   xmlDoc.setProperty("SelectionLanguage", "XPath");
   objNodeList = xmlDoc.documentElement.selectNodes("//xsl:template");
   Response.write(objNodeList.length);
}
```

you can see this thread too:

[StackOverflow - How can I get the XML nodes from this XML in classic ASP (MSXML)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861000/how-can-i-get-the-xml-nodes-from-this-xml-in-classic-asp-msxml)

**Edit:** refering to how to parse a xml string into a MSXML dom document there is a way like you denoted in your comments [boolValue = oXMLDOMDocument.loadXML(bstrXML);](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms754585%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) it's a simple way to create your own XML string and manipulate

Example:

```
var xmlDoc = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0");
xmlDoc.async = false;
xmlDoc.loadXML("<customer><first_name>Joe</first_name><last_name>Smith</last_name></customer>");
if (xmlDoc.parseError.errorCode != 0) {
   var myErr = xmlDoc.parseError;
   Response.Write("You have error " + myErr.reason);
} else {
   Response.Write(xmlDoc.xml);
}
```

Comment: my question really was how to load from a string and not from a file, I could make runs, and sent me .. and pStringXML = "<xml> ...</ xml>" var a = xmlDoc.loadXML (pStringXml)

Comment: I mean string to document, when I do not want to load from a filename from a string but may be a request parameter in my case.